# Implicit route model binding in Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm trying to use implicit route model binding in Lumen but seems it's not working.

Is there anyway to enable this?

```
$app->get('/users/{user}', 'UsersController@get');
```

It's just returning the value in `user` but it's not type hinting it and returning the model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same issue recently and doubt that it's possible. Lumen 5.2 does not use the Illuminate router but [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) instead. [more info on the differences here](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/introducing-lumen-from-laravel#capturing-all-routes)
However, it should be possible to write a custom middleware if that's an option.

Comment: Decided to dump Lumen for Laravel, just too much headache.

Comment: maybe you can try this package https://packagist.org/packages/mmghv/lumen-route-binding,

Comment: @Rob Agreed. Whilst Laravel is great if you’re just knocking together a simple JSON API, as soon as you want anything “useful” (form requests, route–model binding, etc) then you may as well just use Laravel. You can disable the service providers that aren’t needed (session, views, etc).

Answer (score 8):

I created a package to add support for `route-model-binding` in Lumen, Check it out here :

[Lumen Route Binding](https://github.com/mmghv/lumen-route-binding/)

It requires :

```
php >= 7.1
Lumen 5.* || 6.*
```

It supports Explicit binding :

```
$binder->bind('user', 'App\User');
```

Implicit binding :

```
$binder->implicitBind('App\Models');
```

And Composite binding : (bind more than one wildcard together, In situations like `posts\{post}\comments\{comment}` you will be able to bind it to a callable that will resolve the `Post` and the `Comment` related to the post)

```
$binder->compositeBind(['post', 'comment'], function($postKey, $commentKey) {
    $post = \App\Post::findOrFail($postKey);
    $comment = $post->comments()->findOrFail($commentKey);

    return [$post, $comment];
});
```

Also can work with other classes like `Repositories` :

```
// Add a suffix to the class name
$binder->implicitBind('App\Repositories', '', 'Repository');
```

Can use a custom method on the repository :

```
// Use a custom method on the class
$binder->implicitBind('App\Repositories', '', 'Repository', 'findForRoute');
```

Where in the repository class you can do :

```
public function findForRoute($val)
{
    return $this->model->where('slug', $val)->firstOrFail();
}
```